# Dynamic Linq cannot parse long.Parse()

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm using the Dynamic Linq Library to parse a boolean expression. In this method:

```
public static LambdaExpression Parse(SearchQuery query)
{
    string compilableExpression = BuildCompilableExpression(query);

    ParameterExpression parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventListItem));
    return System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, compilableExpression);
}
```

`BuildCompilableExpression` returns this  string:

`"long.Parse(InstanceID.ToString()) == long.Parse(\"2\")"`

Which is correct (`InstanceID` is a property in the `EventListItem`), however, the call to `ParseLambda()` failes with this exception:

`No property or field 'long' exists in type 'EventListItem'`

I've tried parsing an expression that contains `string.Compare()` and that works just fine, so I don't understand why `long.Parse()`doesn't work. I was just wondering if anyone has ever done this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `long` isn't the name of a type, it is a shortcut provided by C#. `Int64` is the technical name, have you tried that? Similarly `String` is the name of the string type.

Comment: Yes it worked. I don't understand though, `string.Compare()` works, even though `string` (lower case "s") is also a shortcut, isn't it?

Comment: @Guvante Go ahead and post your comment as an answer if you want, and I'll accept it since you answer before others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` isn't the name of a type, it is a shortcut provided by C#. `Int64` is the technical name, have you tried that? Similarly `String` is the name of the string type.

Note that `string` might have worked because while C# is case sensitive, the analyzer may or may not be.

Answer (score 2):

The type `long` does not exist in .NET. `long` is a C# keyword and is an alias for the .NET type `System.Int64`. Try using `Int64.Parse(...)`.